# dojo Enhanced Grid not showing any message when no data is there

Tags: dojo

I have an enhanced grid, if i pass an empty json then the grid is not showing any message.

```
var newStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore
({
        data : result
});
GridId.setStore(newStore);
GridId.startup();
GridId.loadingMessage = "Loading";
GridId.errorMessage = "ERROR!!!";
GridId.noDataMessage = "No Data Found";
```

then also its not showing any message.

Comment: Maybe because you called startup before specifying the messages?

Comment: i tried placing it after the messages then also its not working.

Comment: Sorry I can't help more.  I use the new dGrid from SitePen and haven't used EnchancedGrid.  The only other thing I can suggest trying is maybe waiting to set your store until after you set the `noDataMessage` and call `startup`.  That's how I'm using dGrid in my current project.